# How should we handle links to external manga readers?

Tags: discussion, external-links

I've noticed certain [answers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/878/63) link to external manga readers. Many of these manga readers make their money off pageviews and ad-content. I don't think we should be directing traffic to these sites.

Should we remove them and add a reference to the chapter and page(s), rehost these image(s) on Imgur, or do something else?

Comment: Walking a tightrope there - there *may* be free webcomics out there that are freely and readily available to peruse online, just not in English.  If someone were to link to that, would there be a problem?  My gut says no.  If someone were to link to a scanlated manga, then that would be a pretty big deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Unless the link is an article or a wiki page of some sort which explains the topic better (a.k.a. "Also See"), but only an image to illustrate/example an idea, rehosting it on imgur is an easy and appropriate solution.

Directing links to external sites may have unintended consenquences against people whose providers (for example) have blocked one or another manga site. Imgur is neutral grounds, we haven't received complaints about images from imgur not loading.

About referencing a chapter. I don't think we should provide links to external manga readers. Mainly because most of those are illegal hosts/scans. Reference the chapter/page without links, and trust the OP to find it himself in whatever way he sees fit.

Answer (score 4):

If you doubt about where the site is illegal, **don't link to them**. Just indicate the general chapter and page.

If the site is official (as if the same distribution company shares the Manga), then that's OK. But I doubt that exists.

Any link to illegal should be removed, so if you see something that might not be totally clear, **flag the post**, moderators will act on it.